# This procedure works great for the first date but it doesn't remove anything matching the requirement from the second date

Tags: sql, db2

```
DELETE FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
 WHERE 
  COALESCE 
    (
      SUBSTR (ODUDAT, 1, 2) || SUBSTR (ODUDAT, 3, 2)  || SUBSTR (ODUDAT, 5, 2)
    , SUBSTR (ODCDAT, 1, 2) || SUBSTR (ODCDAT, 3, 2) || SUBSTR (ODCDAT, 5, 2)
    ) > TO_CHAR (CURRENT_DATE - 2 MONTHS, 'MMDDYY');
```

ODUDAT is last used . The second date is ODCDAT and it is creation date. The data is in format MMDDYY. I need to delete date rows with Last used date earlier than two months. If the file is created within the last two months but not used those need to be left in the file. The file contains 6893 rows. When i use the above I get 536 rows. It removes older items from ODUDAT but does not touch the ODCDAT. Also If ODUDAT is empty then it reverts to ODUDAT.  I'm not sure how to handle that in the code.

Sample Data
A210407001 *FILE DDMF 040821 BYOD_00003 *FILE PF 021521 021621 DPI2194LO1 *FILE LF 041221 DPI2194LO2 *FILE LF 041221 DSLAMPORT1 *FILE PF 021521 021521 FIXPHYADR1 *FILE LF 042021 –

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by second date , please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: ODUDAT is last used .  The second date is ODCDAT and it is creation date.  The data is in format MMDDYY.  I need to delete date rows with Last used date older than two months.  If the file is created within the last two months but not used those need to be left in the file.  The file contains 6893 rows.  When i use the above I get 536 rows.  It removes older items from ODUDAT but does not touch the ODCDAT.

Comment: A210407001  *FILE     DDMF         040821            
 BYOD_00003  *FILE     PF           021521    021621  
 DPI2194LO1  *FILE     LF           041221            
 DPI2194LO2  *FILE     LF           041221            
 DSLAMPORT1  *FILE     PF           021521    021521  
 FIXPHYADR1  *FILE     LF           042021

Comment: edit your question and add these information in there instead of comments, its hard to follow up on comments

Comment: when it's not used , what you have in your data , is it null or empty?

Comment: EMPTY is what is in the field. I just did a select to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST
WHERE 
COALESCE 
(
  NULLIF
  (
  SUBSTR (ODUDAT, 5, 2) || SUBSTR (ODUDAT, 1, 4)
  , ''
  )
, SUBSTR (ODCDAT, 5, 2) || SUBSTR (ODCDAT, 1, 4)
) < TO_CHAR (CURRENT_DATE - 2 MONTHS, 'YYMMDD');
```

You convert the `MMDDYY` representation of dates (as you showed in the data example) in your columns to `YYMMDD` with these SUBSTRs. Then you compare it to the same string representation of current date minus 2 months. If you need to delete rows with earlier dates, you need `<`.

Here is [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=00fb86670ced09751e4b6de377e1d17c) link with a SELECT statement with the same WHERE clause (i.e. it selects the rows which should be deleted). You may edit the example at the link with some new sample data pointing out to some row, which is either erroneously deleted or not deleted.

Comment: In this code how do i add when it meets criteria?  The above code deleted all the records.

Comment: If you have blank ('') or NULL value in the first column (and not just NULL), the query must be modified with NULLIF function use. The logic is: if ODUDAT is NULL or blank, then use ODCDAT. If the later can be blank as well and, you don't want to touch such a row, then wrap its expression into NULLIF as well. This logic should work for your description. If not, then edit your question with data sample for table of 2 columns and show which rows must and must not be deleted.

Comment: I will add data sample.

Comment: I ran that code and it did delete 540 but it does the opposite of what i need.  All last used dates of 051821 for example are still in the file and those are the ones i need to remove.  I have never hear of dbfiddle thank you for that link.

Comment: You contradict to your own condition provided in the question: "I need to delete date rows with Last used date older than two months". '051821' **is not** older (earlier) than 2 months. Why should it be deleted?

Comment: My apologies for the mistake.

Comment: I want to thank you Mark Barinstein.  Not only for your time but your patience.