# The code below deletes rows utilizing ODUDAT but it does not delete rows when ODUDAT is Empty

Tags: sql, db2

```
DELETE FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST WHERE COALESCE(ODUDAT, ODCDAT,
    CASE
        WHEN ODUDAT <> ' ' THEN SUBSTR(ODUDAT, 1, 2) || SUBSTR(ODUDAT, 3, 2) || SUBSTR(ODUDAT, 5, 2)
        ELSE SUBSTR(ODCDAT, 1, 2) || SUBSTR(ODCDAT, 3, 2) || SUBSTR(ODCDAT, 5, 2)
    END) > TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 2 MONTHS, 'MMDDYY');
```

ODUDAT is last used . The second date is ODCDAT and it is creation date. The data is in format MMDDYY. I need to delete rows with Last used date older than two months. If the file is created within the last two months but not used those need to be left in the file. The file contains 6893 rows. When i use the above I get 553 rows. It removes older items from ODUDAT but does not touch the ODCDAT. I can't figure out why it is ignoring ODCDAT.
Sample data

```
 A210407001 *FILE DDMF 040821 BYOD_00003 *FILE PF 021521 021621 DPI2194LO1 *FILE LF 041221 DPI2194LO2 *FILE LF 041221 DSLAMPORT1 *FILE PF 021521 021521 FIXPHYADR1 *FILE LF 042021 –
```

Comment: Is it the same as here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67603860/this-procedure-works-great-for-the-first-date-but-it-doesnt-remove-anything-mat

Comment: No..i added the case to it.  I tried to figure how to delete the other one but could see and it isn't answered so wasn't sure what to do.  Also, one person helping me gave me the information to better submit so as to not be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE()`  works when dealing with NULL values..

An empty VARCAR() or a CHAR string of blanks is not NULL in Db2.

Also you can't do comparisons of date values using a character MMDDYY format; you'll need to convert `ODUDAT`, `ODCDAT` to a date type and then compare them.

Best solution, build or download (I recommend [iDate](http://think400.dk/downloads.htm)) a User Defined Function (UDF) that will convert numeric/character dates.

then you can simply

```
 DELETE FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST 
  WHERE COALESCE(iDate(ODUDAT,'*MMDDYY')
                , iDate(ODCDAT,'*MMDDYY')
                , current_date)
      > CURRENT_DATE - 2 ;
```

Comment: When the sbustr is not in the code it comes back error An operand of addition is a timestamp and the other is not a duration.  The Dates don't have NULL they are empty.  I'm just at a loss.  Nothing is working that i have tried.

Comment: again, build a UDF (or download iDate) that returns NULL when the character value is not a valid date.